# Problems with Entity passed as argument

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have this code :

```
Public Class myclass
....
Private cont As MyentEntities
.....
.....

Public Sub New( ByRef cnx As MyentEntities)
   .....
    cont = cnx
    .....
End Sub

Public Sub test
.....

If cont.mytable1.Count=1 then

.....
end if 

End Sub
End class
```

'On my main form :

```
.......
Dim E1 as MyEntEntities
Dim m1 as myclass
Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)    
Handles Me.Load 

E1=New MyentEntities
m1=new MyClass(E1)
Fill_entity()
........

End Sub

Private sub fill_entity

E1.MyTable1.Tolist
....
End sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)    
Handles Button1.Click

m1.test

End Sub
```

When I click the button , I get an error :

....the entity of type 'MyTable1'  does not exist in the context.

But I passed E1 with ByRef ?

What's wrong ?

Thank you !

Comment: Passing ByRef in the code you showed is not necessary, unless you plan to actually change the reference itself (rather than its properties).  Are you using Code First in EF?  Or do you have an .edmx ?  Are you sure you have a property/table called `MyTable1`?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework 6.I have EDMX file.I'm sure that I have a table called MyTable1 , and I'm sure also that the entity with this table is working correctly because if I try to use any query against Mytable1 but outside the MyClass , everything works ok .